# C++ returning iterators to two or more class containers

Tags: c++

I'm building an C++ API just for learning purposes and I'll need a class
with two containers. Suppose they're initially of type vector<>.

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
    std::vector<int> containerA;
    std::vector<double> containerB;

  public:
    std::vector<int> *getContainerA();
    std::vector<double> *getContainerB();
};
```

But if someday I'll have to change the type of these containers (to list, for instance), I would not want that the users of this API needed to change anything in their code.

So, considering that containerA and containerB types were changed, when using the getters above, which return vector<>, API users would need to change their code to match the new type of API's containers.

I think that return iterators instead of vector<> can help me with that.

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
    std::vector<int> containerA;
    std::vector<double> containerB;

  public:
    std::vector<int>::iterator beginContainerA() { return containerA.begin(); }
    std::vector<int>::iterator endContainerA() { return containerA.end(); }
    std::vector<double>::iterator beginContainerB() { return containerB.begin(); }
    std::vector<double>::iterator endContainerB() { return containerB.end(); }
};
```

Is this the way how things are done? Is there a better way? Thank you.

Comment: IMHO returning iterators instead, would not solve the problem.The caller will still have to have container specific code.Since you are having `gettter` methods and returning the containers, then how can the caller not care about the type of container.

Comment: Returning iterators won't solve your problem. It seems that you need a member function, which returns a template. Besides, I suggest you going to learn about STL adapter (stack, queue etc. Users can use stack but in fact STL use vector, list etc to simulate a stack). I think your design is not good. So learning about STL adapter and redesign your code.

Comment: You may return `span` or `array_view`.

Comment: Ask yourself what your class should *do* rather than what it should *have*. Prefer designs with no "getters" (which are usually just a way to avoid public data members in letter only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend combining πάντα ῥεῖ's idea and yours: Both define a type alias, and return iterators:

```
typedef std::vector<int> ContainerAType;
ContainerAType::iterator beginContainerA();
```

Also, you'll need a const version as well, so that you can use the iterators on const instances:

```
ContainerAType::const_iterator beginContainerA() const;
```

Consider whether non-const access is even needed.

Consider returning a range of iterators instead:

```
boost::iterator_range<ContainerAType::iterator> containerA();
```

However, to truly protect the client from any changes, you will need to use type erasing iterator. With type erasure, the client does not even need to recompile, if you change from vector to list (but you also have to use pimpl pattern, to achieve that). You could even stop using a container entirely, and return custom iterators, that generate the data.

Boost has you covered: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html Type erasing iterators do have some overhead, due to using a virtual function call internally.

Answer (score 1):

Rather use getters like

```
 const std::vector<int>& getContainerA() const { return containerA; }
```

and let your clients use

```
 std::vector<int>::const_iterator
```

from the reference.

---

> But if someday I'll have to change the type of these containers (to list, for instance), I would not want that the users of this API needed to change anything in their code.

Also you can use a class specific `typedef` to expose the underlying container type:

```
 typedef std::vector<int> ContainerAType;


 const ContainerAType& getContainerA() const { return containerA; }
```

---

Note that handing out iterators is bad, in the sense that these may become invalid upon changes to the underlying containers.

If a client should be notified about changes, you'll need a separate mechanism like e.g. an [Observer](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/cpp/3) .

Comment: Please explain how would this help if tomorrow there is no `vector` but a `list`

Comment: @GauravSehgal I just put a bit more of reasoning.